# How can I ensure that a process in process builder is executing correctly?

Tags: process-builder, email-alert

I've set up a process that send emails to the owner of a lead. It should send and email notifying that there is a new lead.

I've set up an email alert and placed the email receivers.

Where can I check where is the problem?

Comment: Is your process active? Does it actually use the email alert in one of its actions?

Answer (score 0):

Using debug logs may help to see what is happening:

> Using Debug Logs to Troubleshoot Processes
>   Use debug logs to find detailed information about your running processes after they finish running. For example, if a process doesn’t seem to trigger when a record meets the process’s criteria, or if you want to understand the sequence of processes being executed.
>   Available in: both Salesforce Classic and Lightning Experience
>   Available in: Professional, Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer Editions

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_troubleshoot_debuglogs.htm&language=en_US